# TFS Daily scheduled Back-up is Failing

Tags: database, tfs, backup

We have TFS2015.3. And we have scheduled DB backup in TFS using TFS admin console. But we are finding that TFS DB back up failing frequently with below error:

> Exception Message: Write on "\XASDC\public\DASC\IT\BACKUPSQL\XXXXX1234\TFS\Tfs_CollectionA_9859957732898727191F.bak" failed: 1359(An internal error occurred.)
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally. (type SqlException)
>   SQL Exception Class: 16
>   SQL Exception Number: 3202
>   SQL Exception Procedure: 
>   SQL Exception Line Number: 1
>   SQL Exception Server: XXXXX1234
>   SQL Exception State: 1
>   SQL Error(s):
>   SQL Error[1]: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
>       Class: 16
>       Number: 3013
>       Server: XXXXX1234
>       Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
>       State: 1
>       Procedure: 
>       Line Number: 1
>       Exception Data Dictionary:
>       HelpLink.ProdName = Microsoft SQL Server
>       HelpLink.EvtSrc = MSSQLServer
>       HelpLink.EvtID = 3202
>       HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink
>       HelpLink.LinkId = 20476
>   Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Configuration.SqlDatabaseBackupRestoreComponent.
> Execute(String sqlStatement)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Configuration.SqlDatabaseBackup.Backup(ISqlConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
>      at 
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.Jobs.DatabaseBackupJob.TakeFullBackupOfSingleDatabase(IVssRequestContext requestContext, String dataSource, String databaseName, String fullFileName, ITFLogger logger)
>      at 
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.Jobs.DatabaseBackupJob.TakeFullBackups(IVssRequestContext requestContext, BackupSettings settings, List`1 databaseConnectionInfoList, ITFLogger logger)

It is failing only for a particular Collection. We have 11 collections and Back-up is fine for 10 Collections. But for this particular collection, the scheduled Back-up failed. On rerunning the Backup job manually it succeeds. It failed twice in last 4 days.

Kindly requesting your help to get the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it could be a connection issue with high workload, or an issue like "data cannot be read".

Just try below items to narrow down the issue :

- Detach the specific collection from TFS admin console, then re-attach
  it.
- Change the backup location to local machine instead of UNC path (*There is a possibility that caused by the network.*).
- Recreate the `BackupSets` file:

  1. Go to the directory where your back ups are stored
  2. Find something like "`BackupSets.xml`"
  3. Rename it to "`BackupSets_BACKUP.xml`" (or anything else of your liking)
  4. Schedule the backup in TFS Administration Console

Comment: We do not have that much space to store all the back-up files in local machine. Can I try performing the actions you mentioned in the UNC path? Meanwhile I have just tried changing the scheduled time.

Comment: @Chirag Yes, you can try the UNC path, but as I mentioned there is a possibility that caused by the network (It's based on your bandwidth, sessions etc). Whatever You can try the location in LAN.

Comment: I have changed the scheduled time. Since this change(3 days) I have not experienced the failure. I have to monitor for another 1 week to confirm on the stability.

Comment: for the past one week we have not seen any instance of TFS DB backup failures. For me, changing the scheduled time worked. Looks like a network load during the earlier scheduled time. Thanks for giving me a hint on network issue.